# How to reset submodule to repo's master branch?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a repo in github which has some submodules. When I run `git status` in my repo I see the submodules are changed:

```
    modified:   ci (new commits)
    modified:   metadata (new commits)
```

How can I reset my local submodule to be same as origin/master submodule reference? I have tried `git reset --hard origin/master` which only reset local files not submodules.

In addition, I don't have any local changes in these submodules. I think what happens is that I run a `git pull` in the submodule which makes the commit id referenced by my repo changed.

Answer (score 2):

A submodule is a Git repository.

If you want to change which commit is checked out in a Git repository, you enter the Git repository and run `git checkout` there.  So you could:

```
(cd ci && git checkout origin/master)
```

for instance to change the commit that is checked out in the Git repository in the `ci` directory.  You can repeat this for the `metadata` sub-directory that contains the `metadata` Git repository.

Note that this does not change the commit hash IDs recorded in the *superproject* (the current Git repository).  That superproject lists which hash ID the superproject Git should use when the superproject Git runs:

```
(cd <submodule> && git checkout <hash-id>)
```

If you've changed the hash IDs you'd like the superproject to check out—by entering the submodule Git repositories and checking out *other* commits, for instance—you should run `git add` in the superproject to record the new hash IDs into the index for the superproject repository:

```
git add ci metadata
```

and then run `git commit` in the superproject repository, to make a new commit that records these new hash IDs.

The `git submodule` command can do some of this for you:

```
git submodule update
```

tells your superproject Git to run:

```
(cd <submodule> && git checkout <hash-id>)
```

for each submodule according to the hash ID currently stored in the index in the superproject.  On the other hand:

```
git submodule update --remote
```

tells your superproject Git to run:

```
(cd <submodule> && git fetch && git checkout origin/master)
```

in each submodule.  The name `origin/master` actually depends on configuration settings; that's just the default.  There are many additional flags to `git submodule update` to make it do other things.

(I prefer to just enter the submodule and do the things myself, so that I can see what I am doing.)

Comment: `git submodule update --remote` works for me. Thanks.